What does ' a bird of the air ' in Eccl 10:20 stand for?
We read in Ecclesiastes 10:20 :
(KJV):

Curse not the king, no not in thy thought; and curse not the rich in thy bedchamber: for a bird of the air shall carry the voice, and that which hath wings shall tell the matter.

It is intriguing to hear that birds will understand human verbal  communication and pass it on to the person against whom it was made. Looks like the phrase ' bird of
the air ' is a euphemism for espionage . How do Bible scholars interpret the phrase ?

There's a common saying in my country, that when a person is surprised that another person knows something private about them and asks, "How did you know that?" the answer is, "Ah! A little bird told me!" In other words, the source of the information is not going to be given away by the person who learned that private matter.

What an apt saying ! Look at the words " little bird" . It does not shout like a raven or a parakeet , but has to land on your ear to tell something to you !

". .and that which ye have spoken in the ear in closets shall be proclaimed upon the housetops." (Lk 12:3)

Benson answers this question succinctly:

for a bird, &c., shall carry the voice — The king will hear of it by unknown and unsuspected hands, as if a bird had heard and carried
the report of it.

That is, the idea of a bird carrying a message is a metaphor.  The Cambridge commentary is similar:

a bird of the air shall carry the voice The figure is so natural, answering to the “walls have ears” of the Rabbinic, German, English
proverbs, that any more special reference scarcely need to be sought
for, but it is interesting to note the close parallel presented by the
familiar Greek proverb of “the cranes of Ibycos.”

Even in modern English, we still have the saying, "a little bird told me".  Gill is similar:

for a bird of the air shall carry the voice, and that which hath wings shall tell the matter; an hyperbolical expression; showing
that, by some strange and unthought of ways and means, treason, though
so very secret, should be brought to the knowledge of the king and his
ministers; as if a bird, sitting at the window, or flying by at the
same time, should hear and carry it to them: sometimes this is by
means of spies and informers, that kings have in all places, to bring
them news of the behaviour and sentiments of men, of whom such
understand the passage; or by means of such, that bear an ill will to
them, or are faithful subjects to the king.


In Ecclesiastes 10:20, the phrase "a bird of the air" likely functions as a metaphorical reference that draws on the symbolic meanings of birds in other biblical contexts, incorporating elements of both knowledge and royal power.
Knowledge and Perception
In ancient biblical thought, birds, especially those of the sky, were often seen as symbols of knowledge and insight. This is evident in Job 28:20-21, which describes wisdom as being hidden from both "all living" beings and "the birds of the heavens," suggesting that, while birds might have the ability to see things from a great height, they lack the divine understanding that God possesses. The phrase in Job emphasizes that true wisdom is beyond human and even avian comprehension. In this sense, "a bird of the air" in Ecclesiastes could be seen as alluding to the limits of worldly perception, which, despite being able to see much, cannot grasp the full wisdom and understanding that is only accessible through divine revelation.
Power and Authority
Birds of the heavens also appear as symbols of power and royal authority in the Bible. In the book of Daniel, for example, we see the metaphor of a great tree under which "the birds of the heavens had their habitation" (Daniel 4:12, 21). This tree is associated with the power of Nebuchadnezzar, under whose reign both people and animals find shelter and sustenance. Similarly, in the Book of Judith (11:7), the birds of the heavens are subject to the power of Nebuchadnezzar, representing the idea that under his rule, all of creation, from the beasts to the birds, benefits from his dominion.
Thus, in Ecclesiastes 10:20, "a bird of the air" might symbolize those forces or individuals that, although elevated or in positions of apparent advantage (much like birds soaring through the sky), still cannot escape the limitations or divine constraints placed upon them. It reflects a reminder that even those with power or broad vision lack the understanding of God's ultimate wisdom and plan.
Conclusion
Therefore, in the context of Ecclesiastes 10:20, the "bird of the air" can be interpreted as a symbol of both limited knowledge and of worldly power. Birds, although high-flying and capable of seeing far, are still incapable of grasping the wisdom and understanding that is reserved for the divine, echoing a common biblical theme about the limitations of human perception and control in comparison to God's sovereignty and wisdom.
